# How to pass item Click Position in Listview

Tags: android

[This is My Main Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjElI.png) `

```
lvComments.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Subcategories.class);


                intent.putExtra("position", i);



                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This is code i am using for item position`[This is my 2nd Listview its open when  i am clicking on main ListView But This opens in all position and i want to open this 2nd listview on 0th position of main(1ST) Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJjAe.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open second listview only when you click on 0th position then use following code.

```
    lvComments.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Subcategories.class);

                  if(i == 0){
                    intent.putExtra("position", i);
                    startActivity(intent);
                  } else {
                     //do your stuff for other position.
                  }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works for 0th postion, but i want to open new Listview On Position 1? @Jitesh Dalsaniya

Comment: @HarshalDeshmukh See my answer for else part where you will go if your position is not equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

```
lvComments.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Subcategories.class);
                  if(i == 0){
                        intent.putExtra("position", i);
                        startActivity(intent);
                      }else {// do whatever your stuff
                   }
                }
            });
```

In Second Activity

```
    int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0); // 0 will be default value if there is no value in bundle
```